# Parts of the shop not working anymore after going live

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout, debugging, debug

I wanted to put my shop live on wednesday last week. Due to problems from my hoster, this was not possible, so it went live on thursday instead. When it was live, I encountered a problem with the purchase Button. It wasn't working anymore. (In my local version everything works fine). After Debugging for several hours, trying to fix the issue, I at the end thought, maybe  this was a server problem (given the fact that the server was down the day before). When calling the support center I let the support do a test purchase. She told me what she was doing and then clicked purchase and "poooff" the purchase went through. 
I didn't do anything so wtf!?! Anyways I was happy that it worked. Until yesterday!
Around 5pm I guess, cause I got a call from a client, that the purchase button is not working. Till 10.30am everything still worked, cause there were purchases made. 
Calling support center this time, unfortunately didn't have the same effect as yesterday.

I did some minor bugfixing yesterday (CSS stuff). Other things I undid. I have no clue, what went wrong at some point. I don't get error messages, at least none where I would think they have something to do with the purchase button not working. On my local version everything works! Compared the files, they are the same. I'm not a pro, so my debugging skills are limited.

Could someone please take a look [at the page](http://www.bentolunch.de/speisekarte.html) and make a test purchase? The site is in german so please click at a dish, choose a date, and click in den warenkorb.
After this click "zur kasse" and fill in some dummy data click "weiter", choose "auf rechnung, click "weiter". At the review check the two boxes. And click "kaufen".

Usually you should be forwarded to success page, but now just the loadie is shown and nothing happens. Can someone point me in the right direction here? I am searching for hours now and I don't have a promising lead yet.

**Update**

[image: Log from Purchase Button click]

Could this cause the issue? The cookies are already expired, because the server ist 2 hours behind? I changed the cookie expire date to 86400 but that didn't help. So I think I would have to change the date on server.

Comment: Have you been testing across a number of different browsers?

Comment: Yes, all are not working. Chrome, Firefxox, IE, Opera and Safari.

Comment: Ok, and what about things like is the caching enabled/disabled status the same between the local and production install?  Try and determine what differences exist between the setups both in terms of admin settings and server setup.  If you are confident the code base is identical between the two then it can only really be database differences or server setup.

Comment: is there a way to use the repair database tool from magento with 1.8? I tried it but it didn't work. I got the following error: "Corrupted database doesn't support InnoDB storage engine". Is there an alternative?

Comment: Do you have good reason to believe the database may be at fault?  In situations like this it's not a good idea to just to try things for the sake of it.  Try and debug the problem otherwise you may well end up just digging a bigger hole for yourself.

Comment: I have good reason to believe something is at fault. So far I couldn't figure out what goes wrong. So I keep trying to find out. But thanks for your time, so far.

Comment: At this stage I would be looking at differences between local and production setup, also use a tool like firebug to inspect the purchase button and debug the JS which runs when clicking it. Continual loading could indicate a failed AJAX request so use the net panel to see what comes back from the server when trying to place an order.  Also disable JS merging/minification if enabled to rule out a problematic JS file causing an invalid merged file to be created.

Comment: I think I found a difference between local and live. My log file on live server is always 2 hours behind. It's now 12:43 here and logfile shows then 10:43. My local xampp server time seems to be right. I attached a picture to point out what I expect.

Comment: If you run your local shop on XAMPP and your live-shop is running on a Linux machine, there could possibly be a upper/lower case mismatch somewhere. You also checked your var/log/system.log and var/log/error.log, right?

Comment: I don't think a time difference between the server and your local environment is going to be causing this - you need to do some more in depth as per my comment above (as a starting point).

Comment: @Anna Völkl would an upper/lower case mismatch cause an entry in error_log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchase Button is working again. I'm not really sure, what exactly caused the issue, but changing Payment Method did the trick.